# Shall f = (float)f under #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON lead to raising of FE_INVALID if f is a signaling NaN?

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, language-lawyer, c11

Sample code (t0.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

void    print_fe_excepts_raised     (void)
{
    printf("exceptions raised");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO))     printf(" FE_DIVBYZERO");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT))       printf(" FE_INEXACT");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))       printf(" FE_INVALID");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW))      printf(" FE_OVERFLOW");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW))     printf(" FE_UNDERFLOW");
    if (fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)==0) printf(" none");
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
        union
        {
            uint32_t    u;
            float       f;
        }   snan = { .u = 0x7FA00000 };
        snan.f = (float)snan.f;
        print_fe_excepts_raised();
        return 0;
}
```

Invocation:

```
# clang trunk on linux on x86_64
$ clang t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ffp-model=strict -lm
<nothing>
```

Execution:

```
$ ./a.out
exceptions raised none
```

Question: shall `exceptions raised FE_INVALID` be printed?

Comment: F.2.1 says "This specification does not define the behavior of signaling NaNs."

Comment: @IanAbbott Indeed, thanks! In case if signaling NaNs are supported, then what the behavior should / shall be?

Comment: Not defined behavior is undefined behavior.